# Composite verbs with prefix zu: how to deal with infinitives

Tags: verb, prefix

Suppose I want to write a sentence with the verb *zumachen*. It is composite, so in past participles and in constructs as zu + infinitive the added particles go between the prefix and the main verb.

How should I then say:

> I want to close the window ?

Is it:

> Ich will, das Fenster *zuzumachen*?

Comment: As far as I know, the _zu_ in _zu + infinitive_ constructs is never graphically linked to the verb to which it adheres. Or maybe I'm dead wrong about it.

Comment: @indoxica: Indeed, you are wrong. Verbs with separable prefixes have the _zu_ after the prefix, but the form is written without spaces. Thus _zuzumachen_ is correct.

Comment: @chirlu Good to know. As I'm but a poor apprentice in the German language, it's always good to know everything pertaining to it.

Comment: I suppose it's because it's poor: I should have looked up on the Internet for the existence of "zuzumachen". Moreover, my English sentence and my German translation do not match: the second one is wrong because no additional zu was required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just use it in the original form:

> Ich will das Fenster zumachen (I want to close the window)

An example for 'zuzumachen':

> Ich vergaß das Fenster zuzumachen (I forgot to close the window)

But honestly, I can't tell you the grammatical rule when to use which. Maybe someone else can help. Wiktionary calls the second form "erweiterter Infinitiv Aktiv" (extended infinitive active):

http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zuzumachen

Comment: Just a hint, if you're unsure about a sentence, just type it into google, and if you get very few or no results, it's most likely incorrect.

Comment: The rule is essentially that only modal verbs can take an infinitive without _zu_.

Comment: See also http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Infinitiv.html